# mysql query on case when or data between specified date

Tags: mysql

for each relationship manager display all the customer and their total orders,who ordered more than 5 times in the last week or more than 10 times in the last 14 days,there are two tables

1.orders[date,rel. manager],
2.customer[cid,cname].

I am trying like this, thanks.

```
select o.RelationshipManager,c.Name,count(*) total_orders
case
when o.OrderedDate >curdate() -interval 7 day then count(*)
else
o.OrderedDate >curdate() -interval 14 day then count(*)
end
from customer c
join orders o on c.customerid=o.customerid;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.RelationshipManager, c.Name
   , COUNT(*) total_orders
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN o.OrderedDate > curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS oneWeekCount
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN o.OrderedDate > curdate() - INTERVAL 14 DAY THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS twoWeekCount
FROM customer AS c
JOIN orders AS o ON c.customerid=o.customerid
-- WHERE o.OrderedDate > curdate() - INTERVAL 14 DAY 
GROUP BY o.RelationshipManager, c.Name
HAVING oneWeekCount > 5 OR twoWeekCount > 10
;
```

`COUNT` only counts non-null values, the `WHERE` is optional but changes the results (it should reduce the number of records inspected, but makes `total_orders` the same as `twoWeekCount`); the `HAVING` filters the results after the aggregation/counting has been performed.

*In my experience, it is very rare for an aggregate function to be appropriate **inside** a conditional; I'm not even 100% sure there is an appropriate scenario for such use.*